# Regex expression for serial numbers

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I have the following specifications for a regex:

```
-> The string starts with a string of three numbers
-> It is followed by a '-'
-> That is followed by three uppercase vowels
-> That is followed by a '-'
-> That is followed by three numbers
-> That is followed by a final '-' 
-> That is followed by the last three uppercase vowels.
-> Second set of numbers can not equal the first. 
-> The second group of letters can not equal the first. 
-> The groups of numbers may not contain zero.
```

A passable string is:

```
368-IOU-789-AIO.
```

An invalid string is:

```
368-AEO-368-AEI
354-AOU-431-AOU
```

Currently, I have something like this:

```
([0-9]+[0-9]+[0-9]+[/AEIOU/]+[0-9]+[0-9]+[0-9])
```

Comment: sorry about that, my effort was not working at all so I didn't include it. I've edited the original post. @Ruzihm

Comment: Okay which language you're working with ?

Comment: im working with JavaScript! @CodeManiac

Comment: `The groups of numbers may not contain zero.` can you elaborate this condition, it should have only digits `1 to 9` or it should not be `000`

Answer (score 0):

What you have won't work since `+` means "one or more of". For example, the sequence `[0-9]+[0-9]+[0-9]+` will match anywhere between three and an infinite number of digits.

In addition, your current attempt:

- allows for one to an infinite number of vowels (and possibly `/` character);
- doesn't require a vowel set at the end;
- doesn't require the `-` separators; and
- *may* allow for arbitrary content before and after the match.

---

You should be able to use the `{count}` specifier to get an exact quantity. All but *one* of those limitations can be done with any basic regex engine, with something like:

```
^[1-9]{3}-[AEIOU]{3}-[1-9]{3}-[AEIOU]{3}$
```

The `^` and `$` anchors means start and end of string, `[1-9]{3}` gives you exactly three non-zero digits, `[AEIOU]{3}` gives you exactly three vowels, and `-` gives you the literal separator character.

The "groups cannot be identical" rule is a little more problematic. I would just post process for that to ensure it's not violated. The following pseudo-code is what I mean:

```
def isValid(str):
    if not str.regex_match("^[1-9]{3}-[AEIOU]{3}-[1-9]{3}-[AEIOU]{3}$"):
        return false
    return str[0..2] != str[8..10]
       and str[4..6] != str[12..14]
```

The alternative will be a rather complex regex that future developers will probably curse you for inflicting on them :-)

---

Note that your "The groups of numbers may not contain zero" is a little ambiguous in that it may mean *no* zeros are allowed or just `000` is not allowed. I've assumed the former but it's easy adjustable to cater for the latter:

```
def isValid(str):
    if not str.regex_match("^[0-9]{3}-[AEIOU]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[AEIOU]{3}$"):
        return false
    return str[0..2]  != str[8..10]
       and str[4..6]  != str[12..14]
       and str[0..2]  != "000"
       and str[8..10] != "000"
```

Comment: I can't really process the string itself as I'm working with an API that passes in strings to the regex. I won't be able to access the string itself directly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use capture group and backreferences

```
^([0-9]{3})-([AEIOU]{3})-(?:(?!\1)[0-9]){3}-(?:(?!\2)[AEIOU]){3}$
```

[image]

[`Regex Demo`](https://regex101.com/r/yeWCHE/2/)

`The groups of numbers may not contain zero.` From this if you meant only digits between `1 to 9` then you can replace `[0-9]` with `[1-9]`

If you don't want to have `000` then you can add a negative lookahead `^(?!.*000)` to avoid matching `000`